# WebRTC and Wowza streaming on Firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I'd like simply to stream a video/audio from an Axis camera managed by a Wowza Server Engine and display the video/audio on Firefox browser. 
The streaming flow from the camera (H264, AAC 16000) is transcoded with the help of ffmpeg to H264, AAC(48000). This produces 2 audio channels (as visibile in SDP) which allows to be displayed by the browsers after Wowza transcoding to VP8, OPUS and mpeg-ts. 
In Chrome it works fine.
In Firefox (tested 49 and 50beta) some errors occur.

The console gives:
`ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details`

When displaying about:webrtc I have:

From SDP Local

`a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.42.172.126 58085 typ host`

From SDP distant

`a=candidate:0 1 TCP 50 192.42.172.189 6558 typ host generation 0`

Logs about:webrtc :

`(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>)): peer (PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>):default) has no stream matching stream 0-1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>) aLevel=1
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>)): peer (PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>):default) no streams with non-empty check lists
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>)): peer (PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>):default) no streams with pre-answer requests
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>)): peer (PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>):default) no checks to start
(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>)): Error parsing attribute: candidate:0 1 TCP 50 192.42.172.189 6558 typ host generation 0
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>)): peer (PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>):default)/STREAM(0-1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1477400980285000 (id=110 url=<wowza/webrtc url>):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1`

If I change in VHost.xml the value of webrtcIceCandidateIpAddresses to work on UDP (it means from wowza IP 192.42.172.189,tcp,6558 to 192.42.172.189,udp):

`<Property>
    <Name>webrtcIceCandidateIpAddresses</Name>
    <Value>192.42.172.189,udp</Value>
    <Type>String</Type>
</Property>`

I will have the same error in console.
In about:webrtc I will have:

SDP Local

`a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.42.172.126 50662 typ host`

SDP distant

`a=candidate:0 1 UDP 50 192.42.172.189 6974 typ host generation 0`

Logs about:webrtc :

`(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html)): peer (PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default) has no stream matching stream 0-1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html) aLevel=1
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html)): peer (PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default) no streams with non-empty check lists
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html)): peer (PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default) no streams with pre-answer requests
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html)): peer (PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default) no checks to start
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default)/CAND-PAIR(uCnR): setting pair to state FROZEN: uCnR|IP4:192.42.172.126:50662/UDP|IP4:192.42.172.189:6974/UDP(host(IP4:192.42.172.126:50662/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 50 192.42.172.189 6974 typ host generation 0)
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html))/CAND-PAIR(uCnR): Pairing candidate IP4:192.42.172.126:50662/UDP (7e7f00ff):IP4:192.42.172.189:6974/UDP (32) priority=218992869886 (32fcfe01fe)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default)/ICE-STREAM(0-1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html) aLevel=0): Starting check timer for stream.
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default)/CAND-PAIR(uCnR): setting pair to state WAITING: uCnR|IP4:192.42.172.126:50662/UDP|IP4:192.42.172.189:6974/UDP(host(IP4:192.42.172.126:50662/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 50 192.42.172.189 6974 typ host generation 0)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default)/CAND-PAIR(uCnR): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: uCnR|IP4:192.42.172.126:50662/UDP|IP4:192.42.172.189:6974/UDP(host(IP4:192.42.172.126:50662/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 50 192.42.172.189 6974 typ host generation 0)
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html)): peer (PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default) is now checking
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(ice/WARNING) ICE-PEER(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default): no pairs for 0-1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html) aLevel=0
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html)): peer (PC:1477402453964000 (id=114 url=https://192.42.172.189:6560/webrtc/play/index.html):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961`

I tried to find a solution by searching on the net a possible cause, without results.
Could someone help, please ?

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 0):

The WebRTC Firefox connection issues has been resolved with Wowza Streaming Engine 4.5.0.04 updater. Please open a support ticket to request this updater if you do not already have it.

-Jason

Comment: Typo? The latest update from Wowza as per today (Nov 15, 2016) is 4.5.0.03; for more information, see https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?200-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-Software-Updates#updaters

Comment: I am using the version 4.6.0 and I am having the same problem, it works on Chrome and on my Android cellphone but it isn't working on my Firefox Browser (v 51)

Answer (score 0):

Latest stable Firefox (OSX) and 4.7.x of Wowza Streaming Engine and I also do see this issue ;-( Tried setting up an empty Wowza Application to make sure it's not settings related, but that did not help...